# Regular Expression Eclipse

Tags: java, regex, search

I have below string in my Java files and i want to replace with another string in all java files. can you please show me search regex pattern?

following types of string in different java files

```
private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(Foo1.class);
private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(Service2.class);
private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(Data.class);
```

I want to replace with

```
final protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
```

can someone tell me regex search pattern?

Comment: You should not ask for a final solution but for a way to solve your problem. What have you tried before, why are you not able to look into a regular expression tutorial etc? http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger\((.*)\);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the whole string `private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger((.*));` is a suitable regexp for the question?

Comment: `.*` is not going to work...you better use `[^)]*`..also you should elaborate your answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex in eclipse

```
private\s+static\s+ILog\s+logger\s*=\s*LogManager\.GetLogger([^)]+)\s*;
```

Comment: This would also match `private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger();` and you should escape the `.` in `LogManager.GetLogger`